# Function and surface plot Julia

Tags: function, plot, julia, surface

I want to plot a function using surface in Julia. I manage to plot te desired function:

```
x = 0:0.1:4
y = 0:0.1:4
f(x,y) = x^0.2 * y^0.8
surface(x, y, f, camera=(10,30),linealpha=0.3, fc=:heat)
```

However, I would f(*) to be a proper function over which I could also optimize (e.g. utility maximisation in economics). This is my attempt:

```
function Utility(x1, x2)
    u= x.^0.2 .* y.^0.8
    return u
end
```

But it unfortunately does not work. Can anybody help me?

Best

Daniel

Comment: Your `f(x,y)` is a proper function, it's just that it fits in one line. In your `Utility` function (and BTW it is recommended to use lower case for functions), your arguments are `x1` and `x2` instead of `x` and `y`, and you should not broadcast the multiply (use `*` instead of `.*`) for your plot to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Benoit's comment really should be the answer, but let me expand a little bit.

First of all, an inline function definition is not any different from a multi-line function definiton (see the first two examples in the docs [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-functions)). Therefore, doing

```
utility(x, y) = x^0.2 * y^0.8
```

will give you a function that works exactly like

```
function utility(x, y)
    x^0.2 * y^0.8
end
```

However, your `Utility` function is actually different from your `f` function - you are defining it with the arguments `x1` and `x2`, but in the function body you are using `y` rather than `x2`.

This would ordinarily raise an undefined variable error, except that in the code snippet you posted, `y` is already defined in global scope as the range `0:0.1:4`, so the function will use this:

```
julia> y = 0:0.1:4
0.0:0.1:4.0

julia> u(x1, x2) = x1 .^ 0.2 * y .^ 0.8
u (generic function with 1 method)

julia> u(2.0, 0.0)
41-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 0.18205642030260805
 0.3169786384922227
...
```

this is also where your introduction of broadcasting in the `Utility` function (the second difference between your two examples as Benoit pointed out) comes back to haunt you: calling the function while relying on it to use the global variable `y` would error immediately without broadcasting (as you can't exponentiate a range):

```
julia> u2(x1, x2) = x1^0.2 * y^0.8
u2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> u2(2.0, 0.0)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching ^(::StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}, ::Float64)
```

with broadcasting, however, this exponentiation works and returns the full range, with every element of the range exponentiated. Thus, your function returns an array rather than a single number (as you can see above from my call to `u(2.0, 0.0)`. This is what Plots complains about - it doesn't know how to plot an array, when it expects to just be plotting a single data point.

Comment: Thanks, I got the code running. However, just for the sake of completeness: Why is this function not returning any outpout? `a = 0:0.1:4; b = 0:0.1:4; f(x,y) = x^0.2 * y^0.8; f(a,b)` ?

Comment: Running that snippet errors for me, and for the same reason shown in my `u2` example above - if `a` is a range (i.e. an object of type `StepRangeLen`), and you try to do `a^0.2`, that won't work as exponentiation isn't defined for a range. If you want to exponentiate every element in the range, you need to broadcast the `^` operator: `a .^ 0.2`